# strange jquery form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, button, submit

There is a div (form) which opens on the click of a button. There are certain controls in that form like timefields, date, textboxes. When the form opens it is pre-loaded with data. A submit button (Apply Changes) for the form is there as well.

If i simply click on "Apply Changes" button without changing anything in the form, no action takes place but if I change anything say time, date or text, the form gets saved.

How can we define this behavior??

Sorry for the misinterpreting language...

My form is not getting saved if i simply click on "Apply Changes" button. 
Does one of the controls need to be edited prior to saving a form in jquery?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement that behaviour, or what the name for that behaviour is?

Comment: @nnnnnnn: what is the name of this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough way of tracking changes to form data:

```
function dealWithForm(){
  var hasChanged = false,
      $form = $('form');

  $('input, select', $form).on('change', function(){
    hasChanged = true;
  });

  $('form').submit(function(){
    if(hasChanged){
      $form.submit();
      // or post asynchronously with ajax    
      hasChanged = false;
      $.post( // blah blah );
    } else {
      // stop form from submitting.
      return false;    
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  dealWithForm();
});
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. The form shall be saved even if controls are not changed. a little modification on the above would render me to success..Thanks @osahyoun

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the `change` event of all the controls in the form, set a flag on the `<form>` element when the value of a control changes (using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), for instance), then allow the form to be submitted only if this flag is set:

```
$("form").on("change", ":input", function() {
    $(this).closest("form").data("someControlHasChanged", true);
}).on("submit", function(e) {
    if (!$(this).data("someControlHasChanged")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to automatically post changes, or if you wish to post changes when 'apply changes' is clicked. (but if no changes are made, then apply changes should do nothing.

the easiest way is to declare the old values as javascript variables. add an onclick handler to applyChanges which compares each old value with the current form value.
if there is a change, post.

The only issue I can see is " / '  needing to be escaped/unescaped.
a dirtier workaround/hack is to generate invisible div's with the old values.

and generate the old field inside there. then `${oldFIeld1}.text()`  to retrieve it.
note, this is a bit of a hack perhaps someone else has a subtle approach to avoid escaping/unescaping.